# Is $e^{2x} +e^{-3x} + e^{4x} -e^{-5x}=1$ solvable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I am wondering if this equation is solvable or not?

$$e^{2x} +e^{-3x} + e^{4x} -e^{-5x}=1$$

Comment: just graph it...

Comment: I know I could graph it, But I want to solve this algebraically with steps..

Comment: have you tried to make a substitution $e^x=y$ and solve the polynomial equation?

Comment: @Ajay $y=1/8$ (where $e^x=y$) or $x=1/8$ ?

Comment: oh shoot, I made a mistake...Ignore my above comment.

Comment: Correct possible value is $y = 0.885261$ where $e^x=y$. Or approximately $\frac{2213}{2500}$? I've made a mistake again haven't I...@Peter

Comment: It is becoming reaaally complicated algebraically

Comment: IVT should answer the question

Answer (score 2):

With $y=e^x$ render

$y^2+y^{-3}+y^4-y^{-5}-1=0$

$y^7+y^2+y^9-1-y^5=0$

$\color{blue}{y^9}+y^7-y^5+y^2\color{blue}{-1}=0$

The leading term and the constant have opposite signs for positive $y$, so there must be a positive root for $y=e^x$, forcing a real root for $x$.

Comment: at this point does any type of universal root isolation algorithm exist to tell us the number of root this equation has ?

Comment: Descartes' Rule of Signs says no more than three.

Answer (score 0):

The main question here is what do you mean by solvable... If by solvable you mean that there is at least one solution, you can just apply the IVT on the interval $(-\frac 14, 0)$ and conclude that there is at least on solution in that interval. If by solvable you mean that you can write the solution in closed form (using sums, products, radicals...) this may be trickier to show.

Comment: You don't need yo find a finite interval. $(-\infty,+\infty)$ is fine enough resolution.

Comment: Yes @OscarLanzi the infinite interval is fine for existence but, if some numerics is to be used, is is useful to localize the solution in some compact.